# Adding to a list with mouseclick in Python

Tags: python, list

I have made a GUI program that allows the user to place circles and text. I would also like to be able to save the coordinates from the mouseclick, however each time the mouse is clicked, it reads a new coordinate but rewrites it in the list, thus overwriting the previous coordinate.

I understand it is because it is taking the num variable and storing new values in the same variable, but how can I accomplish what I would like to do? I cannot use loops since I am needing the add the coordinates to a list on each button press.

Find the code below:

```
def draw_smth(event):
    global lasx, lasy
    lasx, lasy = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    
    CircleCoords = [1,1]
    
    #canvas.create_line((lasx, lasy, canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y)), 
                      #fill='red', 
                      #width=2)
    x, y = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    (x, y) = canvas.canvasx(event.x), canvas.canvasy(event.y)
   # radius = 40  #change this for circle size
    radius = variable2.get()
    x_max = x + radius
    x_min = x - radius
    y_max = y + radius
    y_min = y - radius

    num = (lasx, lasy)
    
    CircleCoords.append((num)) 
    
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=(CircleCoords))
    
    print(CircleCoords)
    circle = canvas.create_oval(x_max, y_max, x_min, y_min, width=4, outline="yellow")
    circles.append(circle)
    print(circles)
```

Thanks all

Comment: The initialization of `CircleCoords` should not be in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a snipped from another function or in a `main()` somewhere, which would be good to know. As based on the information you provided I am expecting that it this will get called each time an event (such as a mouse click) happens.

Making that assumption each time this gets called you are redefining the contents of the `CircleCoords` list. One way to resolve this is to have your `CircleCoords` list definition at a higher level and updated within the function.

The example below shows a list that gets continually redefined and overwritten within a function, similar to your current code.

```
def myFunc(x):
    list = []
    list.append(x)
    print(list)

def main():
    x = 0
    while(true):
        myFunc(x)
        x += 1
```

In the above execution `list` would continue to print out just the value of x that is passed in because the defintion `list = []` is placed within the function. If you define it outside of the function it will no longer overwrite, but append as intended:

```
list = []

def myFunc(x):
    global list

    list.append(x)
    print(list)

def main():
    x = 0
    while(true):
        myFunc(x)
        x += 1
```

Comment: Brilliant,
thank you very much, I cant believe I didnt realise I was just continually redifining my list =[] over and over on each event... Very large oversite. And yes, it was a snipped from a larger main().
Thank you very much